Do Pawn Shop items have any use other than selling?
Once the Wretched Broker is unlocked, you are able to sell certain plants to them in the Pawn Shop tab such as Nightshade, Cattail, and Wheat. Do these plants have any use outside of selling them to the Broker?


Most of these plants can also be used later for some incantations, Arcane upgrades and Weapon aspects unlocking. So while you can sell them at the Broker, it's advised to keep them to unlock them if you want to get them as soon as possible.

The Wiki's list of Pawn Shop items and those items' pages, mention that only Deathcaps have a singular use in being traded for Bones.
Thalmuses are one of the other plants whose current uses run out fast, only needing 8, a.k.a 4 plantings in total, judging by the Wiki's current info.
Wheat, however, needs 5 plantings.
Cattail is 16, and Nightshade, 27.
